# Theme change for Button + Codenameone

Tags: codenameone

is there any thing got changed for images. Circular button shows different with projections. Button use to display proper circle before. Please see the screenshots for reference. Please advise.

```
Button b;
Button finished = new Button("");
FontImage.setMaterialIcon(finished, FontImage.MATERIAL_CHECK, 8.0f);
Test.makeBorderRound(finished);
Style bg = finished.getDisabledStyle();
finished.setDisabledStyle(bg);
b = finished;
b.setDisabledStyle(bg);  

 public static void makeBorderRound(Component cmp) {
   makeBorderRound(cmp.getUnselectedStyle());
   makeBorderRound(cmp.getSelectedStyle());
   makeBorderRound(cmp.getPressedStyle());
   makeBorderRound(cmp.getDisabledStyle());
   }

public static void makeBorderRound(Style stl) {
    stl.setBorder(RoundBorder.create().
    rectangle(true).
    color(stl.getBgColor()).
    opacity(stl.getBgTransparency() & 0xff));
    stl.setPaddingUnit(Style.UNIT_TYPE_DIPS);
    stl.setPaddingLeft(1);
    stl.setPaddingRight(1);
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

That's the icon peaking out from the edges of the round border. We fixed a bug where the background wasn't painted for some cases.

A simple workaround would be:

```
Button finished = new Button("");
finished.getAllStyles().setBgTransparency(0);
FontImage.setMaterialIcon(finished, FontImage.MATERIAL_CHECK, 8.0f);
finished.getAllStyles().setBgTransparency(255);
Test.makeBorderRound(finished);
```

By setting the bg transparency to 0 the icon will have transparency, this will then get overwritten by the second line after the icons are created.

Comment: Shai, This removes the blue color for the button as well. When can I expect the fix to be applied on the server,

Comment: This happens because of a fix to an issue. This actually fixed the bug, I refined the answer with an additional line of code.